# Loss of numeric data when importing text file to excel with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a macro in VBA which imports text files and make a graph of given data. I'm done with import, but there's a thing with changing formats. Files have one delimiter: "," (comma), and here's an exemplary line:

```
1,1.201E-10,2.381E-8,0.005045,0.566
```

Data is of course in seperate columns after import, but numbers are not read as numbers, because of dots in them. And here's a thing:

When I do it manually, by Search and Select tool, change "." to "," it works perfectly fine.

```
1   1,201E-10   2,381E-08   0,005045   0,566
```

But bad things happen, when I'm trying to automatize this and record a macro by tool Record Macro and do the exact same set of things. When I execute it, the data loss occurs with values with "E". The same line of data looks then like this:

```
1   1,201E-07   2,381E-05   0,005045   0,566
```

Also the last two numbers are on the left side of its cells, as they weren't treated like a numeric values.

I tried to hack this with several different set of actions but nothing works when it comes to make this change automaticly with a use of a macro. Do you think that it could be a problem within import itself?

Here's a full code of my macro (I'm a rookie, so excuse some shortcomings that could be obvious for you):

```
Sub import()


Fname = Application.GetOpenFilename

If Fname = False Then Exit Sub

Sheets("Arkusz2").Select
Columns("A:E").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Selection.ColumnWidth = 8.43


Workbooks.OpenText Filename:= _
    Fname, Origin:=437 _
    , StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True _
    , Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), _
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True




Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("E:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit



ark = ActiveWorkbook.Name

Columns("A:E").Select
Selection.Copy
'Range("A1").Select
Windows("import danych.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Arkusz2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste



Range("A1").Select

Windows(ark).Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveWindow.Close savechanges = True
Windows("import danych.xlsm").Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A1").Select


Range("B4,B5,B6,B8,B10,B11,B12,B21:E100").Select
Range("B21").Activate
Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:=",", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Hope to hear some solutions from you guys.

Comment: Try adding `DecimalSeparator:=".", ThousandsSeparator:=","` `to your Workbooks.OpenText arguments`.  (Or whatever they are in the CSV file)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly fine!

Comment: Glad to help.  I'll post it as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `DecimalSeparator:=".", ThousandsSeparator:=","` to your Workbooks.OpenText arguments. (Or whatever they are in the `CSV` file)